# How can I load a memStream with a Excel .xlsx file and then open it from the memStream?

Tags: excel, windows-7

How can I open an Excel file (.xlsx) that has been loaded into a memory stream? For security purposes, I don't want the file to reside on disk.

Comment: Excel does not support that... which means: what you want is not possible. what exactly is your goal ? Do you really need to open the file in Excel ?